# Survey Rejects Poly-Industrial Programmers

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-developer-survey

I have worked in a couple of different industries recently, but the [new survey](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/12/come-here-often/) only allows a single choice for `Industry`.

Can those be changed to checkboxes?

Comment: Is this for Careers.SE?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/12/come-here-often/

Answer (score 3):

The question is phrased (emphasis mine):

> How would you best describe the **industry you currently** work in?

In your question, you state (again, emphasis mine):

> I have worked in a couple of different industries **recently**,

That might be the case, but you imply that you only work in a single industry *now*, which is exactly what the survey is asking for.

It wants to know where you *work*, not where you've *worked*.

If you are currently working in two or more industries at the same time, then I'd see this as being valid, but I think that's probably *not* the use case for most people.

Even if it was, chances are that they spend the majority of their time concentrating on one over the other, in which case, that would be the piece of data that the survey is trying to capture.

Finally, if you are overly concerned about not contaminating the poll data, there is always the option of *not taking the survey* (I'd hope that's the prime motivating factor here).

Comment: While it's not the majority, a non-trivial percentage of the workforce in the US (~10% in 2005 and climbing every year) is self-employed. It's really not unheard or uncommon to have multiple concurrent clients in different industries.

Comment: @MarkTrapp: While subjective, 10% does not qualify as "most" to me.  Also, the acceleration of that metric would have to be pretty fast in order for it to be considered "most", IMO.

Comment: I've already conceded it's not the majority (or "most"); but "most" surveys don't seek to appeal to only the simple majority or invalidate 10% of the population. 10% is a very large margin of error, and that's only on this one question.

Comment: @MarkTrapp: Yes; myself included.  Right now, I'm working for two different organizations in similar fields; 6 months ago, I was working for three different organizations in three very different fields.